# how to take read_phone_state permission in android 6.0

Tags: android, android-permissions

I got below error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10250 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.

AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.infyco.kp.new_tab, PID: 23149
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.infyco.kp.new_tab/com.infyco.kp.new_tab.Splashscreen}: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10257 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
```

Here is my code:

```
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);
```

it works for the `SEND_SMS` permission , but not with the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission

```
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
```

Comment: Do you have a `<uses-permission>` element for `READ_PHONE_STORAGE` in your manifest?

Comment: check it https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: @Commons ware  ... yes do have it in manifest :)  i want a code to get permission run time even i tried with below isPermissionGranted() but not working ... :(

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting the permission with the same request code (here: 1).

Try this:

```
public  boolean isPermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 2);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}


 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 2: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //do your specific task after read phone state granted
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
 }
```

Use it like this:

```
if(isPermissionGranted()){
    //do your specific task after read phone state
}
```

Also, in your manifest, add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        else
            {
            mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            IMEI_Number_Holder= mTelephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            }
    }
    else
    {
        mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        IMEI_Number_Holder = mTelephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    }
```

Comment: Consider to add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Downvoted for very unusual variable name conventions. Hungarian notations, Full caps, underscores, brackets on new line... don't do it

Comment: [Context for ZUNJAE's comment](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) - it violates the language naming conventions. This should be avoided, especially when it also violates other forms of non-standardized conventions. This isn't compatible with snake_case either